# How to sort a deque of sets using a comparator

Tags: sorting, set, deque

I have a deque of sets named golfTrails.

- The sets are pointers to an object of type GolfCourse*.

  NOTE: It is possible for golfTrails to have empty items.

The GolfCourse is an object that has the fields:

GolfCourse

{

- int courseId;
- string courseName;
- float courseSlope;

}

- The sets are sorted via a sortfunctor based on courseId.
- courseId is a 1-up counter.

I would like to sort the deque based on the lowest courseId in each item in the deque.

For example,

- entry 1 (i.e, the set) in the deque has courses with courseIds 2, 4, 7, 10
- entry 2 in the deque has courses with courseIds 3, 5, 6
- entry 3 is empty
- entry 4 in the deque has courses with courseIds 1, 8, 9

The end result of this sort should be:

- entry 4
- entry 1
- entry 2
- entry 3  (I don't really care if entry 3 ends up being first or last)

As I said earlier, the sets are in sorted order based on courseId, and the items in the sets are pointers to objects.

If I try sorting the deque like this:

```
 sort(golfTrails.begin(), golfTrails.end())
```

it sorts based on address of the pointer.  That is not what I want to do.  I want to sort based on the courseId of the object that is found at that address.

I can't figure out how to do this. I tried creating a comparison operator to pass to the sort and I tried creating a functor to use in defining the deque. Maybe it can't be done??

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is your example worked out in code:

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> d = deque([
    {2, 4, 7, 10},          # Entry 1
    {3, 5, 6},              # Entry 2  
    {},                     # Entry 3
    {1, 8, 9},              # Entry 4  
])
>>> def lowest(entry):
    return min(entry, default=-1)

>>> sorted(d, key=lowest)
[{}, {8, 1, 9}, {2, 10, 4, 7}, {3, 5, 6}]
```

The essential part of the solution is the [key-function](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-key-function) for [*sorted()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted).  That function computes the lowest value for each entry with `-1` as the default for an empty set.